# Meta-analysis with binary variable and weighting with sample size - Is it possible?

Tags: binary-data, meta-analysis, weighted-regression

I am trying to conduct a meta-analysis with my data on private equity performance versus the public stock market. The binary outcome is if private equity outperforms the public stock market (Yes = 1, No = 0).

I have a sample size for each study that comes to the conclusion on whether or not private equity outperforms, and I wish to weight each outcome by sample size.

I do not have proportions of private equity firms outperforming and thus cannot get an effect size using conventional means. Is it possible to conduct a meta-analysis with this amount of information or should I use a different model?

My data looks like this (note that this is just snippet, there are many moderators but not required for my question);

- Number of success = the total samples of funds which outperformed
- Number of failures = the total samples of funds which dod not outperform
- Total sample size = total number of funds across every study
- $\hat{p}$ = Number of success / Total sample size
- Number of failure to sample size = Number of failures / Total sample size

[image]

Comment: would you like to indicate you model  ?